# What is the benefit of putting #undef before #define?

Tags: objective-c, preprocessor

I found these lines:

```
#undef TAG
#define kTAG @"TestRegistration///: "
#define TAG kTAG
```

If TAG never been used, why do they `#undef TAG` before they `#define` it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason to do it if the macro wasn't previously defined. If you expect the macro could be previously defined, though, it's a good idea to undef it first because it makes it clear to the reader of the code that you intend to override the previously-set value of the macro (if any).

If you don't expect the macro could already be defined, you shouldn't use the undef first. That way, if it is (surprisingly!) already-defined, you'll get a warning.

Answer (score 3):

In some versions of C, it is illegal to re-declare a macro unless the definition is exactly the same as the previous declaration.

Therefore this is simply defensive coding to prevent against this issue (although a quick test shows that this restriction does not appear in Objective-C).